# performance: recursive - nonrecursive (IE)

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, recursion

I have 2 functions to calculate n! (factorial). The first is a recursive function, the second a straight loop. I have tested their performance in [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/factorial-recursive-vs-not-recursive). For all browsers I tested the nonrecursive function outperforms the recursive one, *except IE* (tested for v7, 8 en 9). Now I'm very used to IE and jscript being the exception, but in this case I'm cursious: what could be the cause of the difference (in other words, if I want my factorial to be fast in every browser, must I really check for the browser first;)?

The functions used are:

```
//recursive
function factorial(n) {  
 var result = 1,      
 fac = function(n) {    
         return result *= n, n--, (n > 1 ? fac(n) : result);      
       };  
 return fac(n); 
}
//nonrecursive
function factorialnr(n){
  var r = n;  
  while (--n > 1) {   
    r *= r != n ? n : 1;  
  }  
  return r; 
}
```

Comment: Try replacing r *= with r = r *(...) as IE is slow with compound operators. Also try putting in an if loop instead of the ternary operator - more code is often faster when it's simpler. Oh, and in IE 6, the non-recursive version is 7 times faster than the recursive one.

Comment: As you already decrease `n` in the first condition test, `r != n` is always true.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/factorial-recursive-vs-not-recursive/2 does that, but no difference.

Comment: @Gumbo, you're right, it is a remnant of an earlier version using n--

Comment: @Gumbo: and what's more ... without the obsolete ternary, even IE is faster for the nonrecursive function. See http://jsperf.com/factorial-recursive-vs-not-recursive/5

Comment: Here’s another test suite: http://jsperf.com/factorial-recursive-vs-not-recursive/8

Comment: @Gumbo, seen it. The iterative method stays the fastest. For IE I wondered if it would be the use of a ternary slowing things down, but that seems to be not the case: http://jsperf.com/ie-ternary-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked further but couln't find anything on the subject. After testing it seems that removing the ternary in version 1 of the [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/factorial-recursive-vs-not-recursive) made IE behave like other browsers (see [rev 5 of the jsperf-test](http://jsperf.com/factorial-recursive-vs-not-recursive/5)). But testing for the [ternary on it's own](http://jsperf.com/ie-ternary-test) didn't really show differences.

Well, let's leave it to that. What I've learned here is that it's advisable to see if a recursive function can be rewritten in an iterative way. The latter seems to outperform recursion.

Thanks for your answers, appreciated it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the browser is not able to optimize [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).  It doesn't realize that your lambda function to could be rewritten iteratively and eliminate the overhead of a function call.

Browsers aren't really meant to be fully fledged compilers and I wouldn't expect them to be able to perform all the optimizations that traditional compilers perform.  If a certain browser can perform a particular optimization, that's great.  But that doesn't mean all will.

Comment: Tried that as well - http://jsperf.com/factorial-recursive-vs-not-recursive/3 . Tail recursion didn't do much, if I'm doing it right.

Comment: no, what I mean is, the lambda function is using tail recursion also.  That's probably why it's slow.

Comment: the question was not about the recursion itself, but about the cause of all (tested) browsers *but IE* are faster using an iterative function for the factorial.